# Check for child object property existence

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create base class which checks if child class has property:

```
# base-filter.ts
export abstract class BaseFilter {
    constructor(
    ) {
    }

    fromObject(filterData: {}, throwOnInvalid = true): BaseFilter {
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(filterData)) {
            if (!(k in this)) {
                if (throwOnInvalid) {
                    throw new Error('Filter key ' + k + ' does not exist');
                }
            } else {
                this[k] = k;
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
}

# person-filter.ts
import { BaseFilter } from './base-filter';

export class PersonFilter extends BaseFilter {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Now setting values:

```
const personFilter = new PersonFilter();
personFilter.fromObject({
    id: 1,
    foo: 'ahv'
});
```

'id' should pass, 'foo' should throw error. But both throw errors.

I have tried also following, no cigar.

```
if (!this.hasOwnProperty(k))
```

Comment: `id: number;` does not add an `id` property to your `personFilter` object; it merely tells TypeScript that it should be prepared to allow an `id` property to be set to a `number` on any object typed as `PersonFilter` at some point.

Comment: Suggestions: `fromObject` should be static. `this[k]=k` should be `this[k]=v`. `filterData: {}` should be `filterData = {}`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thx, I gave them defaults and it worked.

Comment: @NinoFiliu `fromObject` cannot be static. `this[k] = k` was typo. `filterData` - I want to type-declare, not to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `id:number` doesn't assign a value, it types it.

If you use typescriptlang.org/playground you can see your `PersonFilter` class compile to:

```
// typescript
class PersonFilter extends BaseFilter {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

// compiled javascript
class PersonFilter extends BaseFilter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no variable assignments, id and name properties just don't exist. With the compilerOption "strictNullChecks" set to true, your code will produce a compile error. Now, if you assign default properties to these, you'll get their assignments:

```
// typescript
class PersonFilter extends BaseFilter {
    public id: number = undefined;
    public name: string = undefined;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

// compiled javascript
class PersonFilter extends BaseFilter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.id = undefined;
        this.name = undefined;
    }
}
```

The above accomplishes what you're after. However, it's not ideal. Ideal is making use of interfaces.

```
abstract class BaseFilter {

    constructor() {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected fromObject(filterData: {}): BaseFilter {
        return Object.assign( this, filterData );
    }
}

interface IPersonData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

class PersonFilter extends BaseFilter implements IPersonData {

    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    fromObject( filterData:IPersonData ): PersonFilter {
        return super.fromObject( filterData ) as PersonFilter;
    }

}
```

In this solution, we're filtering the properties by the input type while still reusing the "fromObject" logic. By managing the input, we can completely skip the checking altogether.